# Remote Visual Studio Code on Rasperry Pi via X11

Tags: xorg, vs-code

Is it possible to transport the VSCode window via X11?

I've set up an headless RPi v3B+ and installed the 32-bit ARM Version of [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download).

I connect to the PI via ssh `ssh -Y pi@x.x.x.x`. Graphical programs like `xeyes` do work! Starting VSCode does not return anything:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ code
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Comment: I just tried it on a 3B+ - I wouldn't bother - the CPU hits 80-100% when code is idle

Comment: I do bother as this is a POC. `ps -eaf | grep code` does not return any results. The problem ist not high CPU, it's the fact that _nothing_ is happening. If this would work I could upgrade my hardware to a RPi4.

Comment: Fair enough - you must've done something wrong, because it runs - oh, and it's only just usable on a pi4 - what's the output of `which code` ... then `file $(which code)` ... perhaps `code` is not the right `code` on your system, maybe you've installed something else called `code`

Comment: `(which code)` => `/usr/bin/code: symbolic link to /usr/share/code/bin/code`  
I'm 100% sure `code` is correctly installed since I can connect to my pi via xorg session and start `code` successfully!

Comment: right .... have you tried `ssh -X` instead?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
I am running a PI4 and I'm logged into the desktop over X11 using Xming. Most/many programs work fine. I've been writing python in Thonny for instance. I installed the latest version of vscode as per [these instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/raspberry-pi).

Starting VSCode does not return anything, as per the original post.

Adding the "--verbose" flag generates more useful output.

```
$ code --verbose |grep -i error
[3409:1104/094859.425736:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] Display.cpp:977 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Unsupported GLX version (requires at least 1.3).
[3409:1104/094859.426075:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(852)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Unsupported GLX version (requires at least 1.3).
[3409:1104/094859.426927:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1489)] eglInitialize OpenGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
[3409:1104/094859.431862:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] Display.cpp:977 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Unsupported GLX version (requires at least 1.3).
[3409:1104/094859.432735:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(852)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Unsupported GLX version (requires at least 1.3).
[3409:1104/094859.433992:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1489)] eglInitialize OpenGLES failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[3409:1104/094859.434910:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(21)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
[3409:1104/094859.488546:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[3422:1104/094859.704051:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] Display.cpp:977 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Unsupported GLX version (requires at least 1.3).
[3422:1104/094859.704378:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(852)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Unsupported GLX version (requires at least 1.3).
[3422:1104/094859.704619:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1489)] eglInitialize OpenGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
[3422:1104/094859.709321:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] Display.cpp:977 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Unsupported GLX version (requires at least 1.3).
[3422:1104/094859.709616:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(852)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Unsupported GLX version (requires at least 1.3).
[3422:1104/094859.709780:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1489)] eglInitialize OpenGLES failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[3422:1104/094859.710269:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(21)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
[3422:1104/094859.777082:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
  'ignore-certificate-errors': false,
[3432:1104/094900.004554:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] Display.cpp:977 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Unsupported GLX version (requires at least 1.3).
[3432:1104/094900.004898:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(852)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Unsupported GLX version (requires at least 1.3).
[3432:1104/094900.005069:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1489)] eglInitialize OpenGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
[3432:1104/094900.020428:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] Display.cpp:977 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Unsupported GLX version (requires at least 1.3).
[3432:1104/094900.020688:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(852)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Unsupported GLX version (requires at least 1.3).
[3432:1104/094900.020839:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1489)] eglInitialize OpenGLES failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[3432:1104/094900.020998:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(21)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
[3432:1104/094900.137141:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[main 2022-11-04T16:49:00.353Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/taeron/.config/Code/User/settings.json'
```

I observed that several of the errors relate to the gpu so next I tried:

```
$ code --verbose --disable-gpu |grep -i error
  'ignore-certificate-errors': false,
[3538:1104/095015.309129:ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported.
[3538:1104/095015.507995:ERROR:x11_software_bitmap_presenter.cc(141)] XGetWindowAttributes failed for window 25165827
[3538:1104/095015.510058:WARNING:connection.cc(41)] X error received.  Request: CreateGCRequest, Error: DrawableError{.sequence = 36, .bad_value = 25165827, .minor_opcode = 0, .major_opcode = 55}
[main 2022-11-04T16:50:15.544Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/taeron/.config/Code/User/settings.json'
[3538:1104/095015.619564:WARNING:connection.cc(41)] X error received.  Request: FreeGCRequest, Error: GContextError{.sequence = 38, .bad_value = 31457280, .minor_opcode = 0, .major_opcode = 60}
```

Now fewer errors remain. Does this move anyone closer to an answer?

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: is that rhetorical?

Comment: no ... you posted additional information ... it belongs in the question, not in an answer